# Convert Map Route to tracks or GPS Coordinates

Tags: google-maps, navigation, maps, openstreetmap, gpx

From a navigation Route from Point **A**(*coodinate/point*) to Point **B**(*coodinate/point*) -

i want to know if i can convert them into a list of GPS coordinates(*or traces*), with some fixed interval i.e, these coordinates will trace out the path of the route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way using [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/)
If we send this [request](http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.385983,52.496891?overview=full&steps=true&alternatives=false)-

We'll get the output in JSON format, where the locations are listed. Added a sample code which i made-

```
URL = "http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/"+args.coord+"?overview="+args.ovw+"&steps="+args.steps

r=requests.get(URL, verify=False)
data = r.json()    

if data["code"]=='Ok':
    for i in range(len(data["routes"])):
        for j in range(len(data["routes"][i]["legs"])):
            for k in range(len(data["routes"][i]["legs"][j]["steps"])):
                for l in range(len(data["routes"][i]["legs"][j]["steps"][k]["intersections"])):
                    locations_i.append(data["routes"][i]["legs"][j]["steps"][k]["intersections"][l]["location"])
```